# How to connect kafka to ftp

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to kafka 
I want to connect from ftp server and listen if there is new file is coming it should come to kafka queue.

Any suggestion how to do it ?

Answer (score -1):

Check out the list of [connectors here](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/) -- there's two currently listed.